# Why is Main method private?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, methods

New console project template creates a Main method like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Why is it that neither the `Main` method nor the `Program` class need to be public?

Comment: @jacerhea: No. `class Program` is internal, `Main()` is private.

Comment: Is "New console project template" a reference to Visual Studio? If so, it would be appropriate to add the 'visual-studio' tag.

Comment: @DavidRR Yes, it's a reference to VS, but it is irrelevant to the question though.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The entry point of a program is marked with  the `.entrypoint` IL directive. It does not matter if the method or the class is public or not, all that matters is this directive.

Comment: That also means you don't even have to call the main method "Main". The C# Compiler enforces that, but other .net languages can use whatever they want.

Answer (score 31):

The `Main` method shouldn't need to be called by anyone.

It is actually marked as the entry point for execution in the EXE itself, and therefore has no outside callers by default.

If you *WANT*, you can open it up to be called by marking `public`, e.g. if you are turning a console app into an API.

Comment: Even if the functionality of the console program should be callable directly by other assemblies, it is often a bad idea to open up `Main`. It is better design to expose a public Facade that external programs can call. `Main` handles command line arguments and then calls into the same Facade.

Comment: @Anders: Fair point, but we are just talking about feasibility, not design.

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can mark the `main()` method as public, private or protected. If you want to initiate the entry point by any external program then you might need to make it public so it is accessible. You can mark it as private if you know there is no external usage for the application then it is better to make it private so no external application access it.

```
public class MainMethod
{
    private  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: By default class members are private, so no need to put the "private" access modifier in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Public or Private keyword doesn't make a difference in this case, it completely depends on usage and scope of the application. Use below mentioned keywords in different scenarios.

1. Public - If we want to initiate entry point by any external program, then you might need to make it public so it is accessible.
2. Private - If we know there is no external usage for the application, then it is better to make it private so no external application access it.