# Why does my program work if my Main method in C# is private?

Tags: c#, clr

By default the type modifier for every member in a class is a private, even the Main() function type modifier is private. How does the CLR call the main method which is not visible to the outside world?

Comment: Maybe through [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)#C.23)?

Comment: By contrast, Java requires its `main` method to be public. It's invoked by the launcher using reflection, so in theory, it's possible to invoke a non-public `main` too, but the launcher actually checks for the public flag and enforces it. (Also by contrast, Java doesn't have `entrypoint`. The method has to be named `main`, has to be static and public, has to return `void` (not `int`), and has to take a single argument of type `String[]`.)

Comment: The CLR manages to call other private methods; what makes Main special that it ought to be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Thats not true.</strike>

It has to be public. For e.g. `public static void Main()`.

EDIT: Here is what I found & **learned** today, on why `Main` need not be `public`. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9184c55b-4629-4fbf-ad77-2e96eadc4d62/

Answer (score 7):

The CLR does not care about the accessibility of `main`. "Visible to the outside world" only applies to the *code*, not the *runtime*.

Answer (score 3):

Try using **ildasm** on your code and lookout for the main method

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint // this is something the CLR is interested in
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right,

it's marked as an entrypoint. Check this question: [Why is Main method private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110184/why-is-main-method-private)