# Why is a program main method static?

Tags: c#, static, main-method

I always thought (assumed) that the `Main` method was static because you cannot have multiple instances of it (Correct me if that's wrong). The `Main` method is the start point of your program and thus you can have only one.

So if I have

```
class Program
{

   static void Main(String[] args)
   { // something
   }

}

class OtherClass
{

   void Test()
   { 
      Program p1 = new Program();
      Program p2 = new Program();
      Program p3 = new Program();
      Program p4 = new Program();

   }

}
```

all instances of Program will share the same `Main` method and so there will always be one start point.

Am I correct? Because I just googled this out of curiosity and found DIFFERENT answers to it on the Internet.

Is this explanation ALSO correct for the main method being static?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I didnt know it mattered. the concept of the main method is the same for every language. but c#

Comment: You can only call methods in a class without instantiating it when the methods are `static`. But your example is a little bit odd

Comment: Would you mind linking those different answers in the web?

Comment: " the concept of the main method is the same for every language". No.

Comment: You're confusing the notion of a method (of which there can be only one instance) with the notion of a class (of which there can be many instances). If I have two Foo class instances (a, b) and call a.Bar() and b.Bar() the same method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entry point method were not `static`, someone would need to create an object first. The question is then: create an object of which class?

> I always thought (assumed) that the Main method was static because you cannot have multiple instances of it

You can't have instances of methods. Methods reside in the `Code` section of a DLL and are not copied to the heap. You can only have multiple threads running in the same method.

> The Main method is the start point of your program and thus you can have only one.

As before: If we consider signatures, there is only one method, independent if it's static or not, because they are not instantiated.

> all instances of Program will share the same Main method ...

Depends on what you understand by the term "share". All objects will have the method, yes.

> ... and so there will always be one start point.

The reasoning behind it is wrong. You have many instances of `Program` but that doesn't matter to the amount of methods.

Comment: If the CLR can find the class containing the main method, it could most definitely instantiate the class. Private constructors seem to be a bigger issue. Not to mention, objects are re-usable, and the CLR would have no further use for the object after calling main, so a functional approach seems more logical

Comment: @VinceEmigh: how would it find the main method? Based on which critiera?

Comment: Based upon the same criteria as it finds the static main method, except for the requriement that it be a static method. However, I see a larger issue in cases where the respective class has no parameterless constructor; without knowing what arguments to pass, the CLR could *not* "most definitely instantiate the class", as suggested by @VinceEmigh .

Comment: The [same way it currently locates the main method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6781303/2398375). Of course the CLR will be able to find the main method. It  has to call it. @O.R.Mapper That is another good reason, the  lack of a proper constructor parameters. The CLR won't know what to pass to it. But those problems are still there with a static method aswell. I'm pretty sure it's due to the CLR not needing to re-use the object, thus making it a waste