# C#: Adding 3 numbers using the data type int and print their sum

Tags: c#, console-application

Here is my code in C#: Once this program runs it easily terminates and I can't see  its output, can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int sum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
        {
            int total;
            total = num1 + num2 + num3;
            return total;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nFunction to calculate the sum of two numbers :\n");
            Console.Write("--------------------------------------------------\n");
            Console.Write("Enter a number1: ");
            int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a number2: ");
            int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a number3: ");
            int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum of three numbers is : {0} \n", sum(n1, n2, n3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks fine. what's the problem? a compiler error -> which? a runtime exception -> call stack?

Comment: You can't see anything because your program terminates immediately after the last Console.WriteLine. Just add a Console.ReadLine() after the last line and you will have the time to read the result

Comment: okey I'll try to do ...thank you Steve

Comment: Run without debugging CTRL+F5.

Answer (score 9):

You need something that would prevent console window close like `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Main() method is required in a public class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int sum(int num1, int num2, int num3)
        {
            int total;
            total = num1 + num2 + num3;
            return total;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nFunction to calculate the sum of two numbers :\n");
            Console.Write("--------------------------------------------------\n");
            Console.Write("Enter a number1: ");
            int n1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a number2: ");
            int n2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter a number3: ");
            int n3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe sum of three numbers is : {0} \n", sum(n1, n2, n3));
        }
    }
}
```

Check here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/p9E9Rw

Comment: Public Main() method is not required in a public class

Comment: that is not quite true, and it achieves [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13680541/1132334),

Comment: Check the Link which I shared. 
It seems to be working

Comment: interesting. .net fiddle really fails to build OP code saying, 'Fatal Error: Public Main() method is required in a public class'. VS 2017 on 4.7.1 compiles just fine without making anything public.

Answer (score 0):

Run the program using CTRL + F5

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the console code `Console.ReadKey();` after the `Console.WriteLine` code.

You can also use the `Console.ReadLine();` code, after the `Console.WriteLine` code.

So it waits for you to press a key before shutting down the Console Window.